# Bubblewrap error on iOS7 in Rubymotion

Tags: ios7, rubymotion, xcode5

I downloaded iOS7 GM earlier and an the following error appeared when building on simulator and/or device:

*Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NameError', reason: 'uninitialized constant BubbleWrap::Device::Camera::KUTTypeMovie (NameError).*

What's strange is that I only require bubble-wrap/core in my Rakefile. Also the only functions I use from bubblewrap are BW::JSON and App.Persistence.

If I change the xcode-select path back to xcode4, the app runs again.

Any ideas?

P.S. I have the latest rubymotion and (I think) the latest BubbleWrap (since in the Gemfile, I have the following line, but I'm new to rubymotion/ruby:

```
gem 'bubble-wrap', :git => 'https://github.com/rubymotion/BubbleWrap.git'
```

Edit: Also tried requiring bubble-wrap/camera (even if I don't use the camera), updating xcode command line tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I was a little bit to hasty. From @rubymotion on Twitter, GM is not supported yet but should be really soon. Meanwhile, a user on the rubymotion google groups post a [monkey patch](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubymotion/YZz1bP5r-G4)